# How to change subnet mask and DHCP enabled flag in C++ and Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, networking

Does anyone know how to change the subnet mask and the DHCP enabled flag on Windows XP / Vista / 7 from a C++ program?

The Windows API has a GetAdaptersInfo() routine which will give you that information, but I need the counterpart SetAdaptersInfo() which doesn't seem to exist.  I've looked all over MSDN and the web and don't see how to do it on newer-than-Windows-NT machines.

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this with the IPHelp API, but you need to use the functions
AddIPAddress, DeleteIPAddress etc.